# How to create Ruler with dashed line in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I want to create something like this image below
[image]
how do I create this in Swift Core Graphics with dashed line and
I also want to create this in rounded form think gas tank dial or speedometer.

my current code is below

```
    let dashes: [CGFloat] = [2, 2]

    let dashedLine = UIBezierPath()

    dashedLine.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height/2))

    dashedLine.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height/2))

    dashedLine.setLineDash(dashes, count: dashes.count, phase: 0)

    dashedLine.lineWidth = 5

    UIColor.black.setStroke()

    dashedLine.stroke()
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this ruler?

Comment: take input of weight and/or height

Comment: Can you provide the full code?